# How to delete chips in Material UI

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

So I have a bunch of chips that were rendered as a user types in a text field and selects on create. Then a chip shows up with the text. I want to have the functionality to delete the chip. This is the sandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-xi9hr?file=/demo.js. I want to specifically know what my `handleDelete` function will do

```
import React from "react";
import Avatar from "@material-ui/core/Avatar";
import Chip from "@material-ui/core/Chip";
import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";
import { useState } from "react";
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";

export default function OutlinedChips() {
  const [hashtag, setHashtag] = useState("");
  const [numberOfHashtags, setNumberOfHashtags] = useState(0);
  const [arrayOfHashtags, addHashtag] = useState([]);
  const handleDelete = () => {
    console.log(hashtag);
  };
  const handleHashtagChange = event => setHashtag(event.target.value);

  const handleClick = () => {
    console.info("You clicked the Chip.");
  };
  const newHashtag = () => {
    if (numberOfHashtags < 3) {
      setNumberOfHashtags(numberOfHashtags + 1);
      addHashtag(arrayOfHashtags => arrayOfHashtags.concat(hashtag));
    } else {
      console.log("Too much hashtags");
    }
  };
  const Hashtags = arrayOfHashtags.map(h => (
    <Chip
      size="small"
      avatar={<Avatar>#</Avatar>}
      label={h}
      onDelete={handleDelete}
    />
  ));
  console.log(arrayOfHashtags);
  return (
    <div>
      <TextField
        size="small"
        inputProps={{
          style: { fontSize: 15 }
        }}
        id="outlined-multiline-static"
        multiline
        rows={1}
        placeholder="Description"
        variant="outlined"
        value={hashtag}
        onChange={handleHashtagChange}
      />
      <Button color="primary" onClick={newHashtag}>
        Create!
      </Button>
      {numberOfHashtags > 0 ? Hashtags : ""}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
const handleDelete = (h) => () => {
  addHashtag((arrayOfHashtags) =>
    arrayOfHashtags.filter((hashtag) => hashtag !== h)
  )
}
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-8yh8t?file=/demo.js:448-589

Comment: cool. yet, while this works, it works since its using default 'x' delete icons on the chips. if you're using custom delete icon this won't work. You first need to pass the props to your custom delete icon (in order to allow MUI to bind the action to clicking on it), when even after this is done, the delete function gets the synthetic event as the param, not the chip label, so its more complex (still thinking what's the best way to get from the synthetic event on the custom 'x' icon to the chip label...)

Answer (score 2):

The first think you should do is bind a key for each Chip item, so onDelete handler you can decide which chip you should delete in your array. Finally, filter your array to remove that item with match key.

I think you should read Material Docs carefully, It's already have a example about delete a chip, here is the link: https://material-ui.com/components/chips/

And here is my solution: [Codesanbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-ht2ng?file=/demo.js)

Comment: I had a similar issue, since the state is just the raw strings you don't need `.key`, and adding it causes all of the chips to be removed

Answer (score 0):

Try this.. Pass the chips which you want to delete and `this.selected_search_tags` is the variable in which all chips are stored..

```
remove(fruit: string): void {
    const index = this.selected_search_tags.indexOf(fruit);
    if (index >= 0) {
      this.selected_search_tags.splice(index, 1);
    }
  }
```

Comment: This mutates the state, I don't think it would update the component